# Call Incremental Datasets Created by Macro Function

Tags: syntax, sas, macros, sas-macro

I have a macro variable called `max_attempts` I created from a a PROC SQL that equals 4 for my current datafile. Then, I used a macro function to create datasets up to `max_attempts` so now I have `attempt1_table`, `attempt2_table`, `attempt3_table`, and `attempt4_table`. Now I'm having trouble merging the 4 datasets.

```
data final_table;
    set attempt1_table - attempt&max_attempts._table;
run;
```

[image]
The inputted datafile will have a different `max_n` each time, so I'm using macros to account for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you everyone for your help! It was two issues, the number has to be at the end of the dataset name when using the `-` shortcut and using `trimmed` to remove leading spaces.

```
proc sql feedback;
    select max(max_attempts)
        into: max_attempts trimmed
        from analysis_data;
quit;    

    
data analysis_table;
    set unknown_table attempt_table1 - attempt_table&max_attempts;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

The `-` shortcut only works if the number is at the end of the dataset name. Rename your datasets to be `round_table1`, `round_table2`, etc.:

```
data final_table;
    set round_table1 - round_table&max_n.;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still getting the same error.
(NOTE: Line generated by the macro variable "MAX_N".
round_table       4
ERROR: Missing numeric suffix on a numbered data set list (WORK.round_table1-WORK.round_table).
ERROR 22-322: Syntax error, expecting one of the following: a name, a quoted string, (, ;, CUROBS, END, INDSNAME, KEY, KEYRESET, KEYS, NOBS, OPEN, POINT, _DATA_, _LAST_, _NULL_.  
ERROR 200-322: The symbol is not recognized and will be ignored.)
There are many spaces between attempt_table and 4 in the log, so maybe it's that?

Comment: Do not add spaces into the macro variable when you create it.  If you use SQL then make sure to included the TRIMMED keyword.  Or just remove them by recreating the macro variable. `%let max_n=&max_n;` will remove the extra spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `trimmed` option of the `into :macrovar` clause in order to remove the leading spaces that cause `set attempt1_table - attempt&max_attempts._table;` to resolve into erroneous syntax.

Example:

```
proc sql noprint;
  select <computation-for-max-attempts>
  into :max_attempts trimmed /* removes leading spaces when column is numeric */
  from ...
  ;
quit;
```